# Splitting string using multiple delimiters Java

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

I would like to split a string using multiple delimiters.  Right now I am using this: 
`String delims = "[\\s;.,:'!?()]";`
 which seems to work fine for those characters, but when I try to add the `-` character, it yells at me.  How can I use all of these characters plus `-` as delimiters to split my string?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you putting that character?  That would be read as a range in a regex and that is probably why it doesn't like it.

Comment: It yells. Cool. What compiler or runtime do you use that has this kind of error reporting?

Comment: I tried to just put it in amongst the others- where should I put it so that it knows that I want to use it single character as a delimiter?

Comment: Can you try and keep the dash at either the end or the beginning of your square brackets ... e.g.[\\s;.,:'!?()-]

Comment: I'm using Eclipse...it gives me a regex error- "illegal character range near index 5" if I try to add \- or |- to the existing string

Comment: I used it as the last character and it worked.  Thank you so much!  I feel like an idiot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` has a special meaning in character classes, indicating ranges. (E.g. `[0-9]` will match any digit.)

However, if you put if you put it either as the first character or the last it will be matched as a literal `-`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  I tried it as the last character and it worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @mkjo0617: You're very welcome. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers, and select the answer that you feel helped you the most as the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

- inside the character class has a special meaning. It is usually used to select a range of characters like: [a-z] ... In order to match the dash alone ... either keep it in the beginning or the end

I just tried this and it worked

```
  String regex = "[\\s;.,:'!?()-]";
  String text = "jatin-shah-testing";

  String[] tokens = text.split(regex);
  for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
```