# What is the correct format for passing regex expression like ![,?.\_'@+] in Java String split method?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the ff. delimeters `![,?.\_'@+]` in my
`str.split("![,?.\_'@+]")`. But, it cause an error when the program is compiled which states that `\_` is an illegal escape character. I have tried to remove it and just pass `![,?.'@+]` instead, however string was not being split even if it contains `?, @ and .` character.

Comment: Escape the backslash to match backslash, `str.split("![,?.\\_'@+]")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java Maybe the accepted answer can help you

Comment: There is nothing in [*How to split a string in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) about how to split a string using a character class with *multiple* symbols. `Pattern.quote` cannot be used here.

Comment: Well, this one - [*Splitting string using multiple delimiters Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774500/splitting-string-using-multiple-delimiters-java) - is similar, but it does not explain that in Java, the `[` symbol **must be escaped** inside a character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the symbols into a character class and escape `[`, `]` and `\` there:

```
str.split("[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]]")
```

The `[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]]` character class matches a single character from the set you specified (`!`, `[`, `,`, `?`, `.`, `\`, `_`, `'`, `@`, `+`, or `]`).

Note that `_` is not a special regex metacharacter and does not have to be (and should not be) escaped. If you need to also add `\` character to the character class, you need to use 4 backslashes to match a literal `\` in the input.

Note that whenever you need to add a hyphen to this regex, you should put it right at the beginning or the end of the character class. Please refer to  [*Splitting string using multiple delimiters Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774500/splitting-string-using-multiple-delimiters-java) that dwells on the problem of how to match a hyphen inside a character class in a Java regex.

If you want to get rid of any empty elements in the resulting array, replace all the split characters at the start of the string, and apply a `+` (one or more occurrences) quantifier to the character class (here is an updated answer with a whitespace added to the character class):

```
str.replaceAll("^[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]\\s]+, "").split("[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]\\s]+")
```

Comment: thanks! it works! But just another question, I added `\\s` so it is now `str.split("[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]\\s]")` but for some string like `sample, code! exec` the split returns ['sample', ' ', 'code', ' ', 'exec']. What will I gonna do to get rid of the extra space? The problem occurs when the space is next to a special character.

Comment: That is not a big problem, just add a `+` quantifier to match one or more split characters: `str.split("[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]\\s]+")`. If you want to get rid of leading empty elements, use a replace before splitting: `str.replaceAll("^[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]\\s]+, "").split("[!\\[,?.\\\\_'@+\\]\\s]+")`